# nested filter query in apache solr

Tags: java, solr

I have indexed huge data from database to apacheSolr, problem i I am not able to querying it , here I am sharing my java code

```
      parameters.set("q", "*:*");
      parameters.set("fl", "id,propertyName,locality,hotels");
      parameters.set("fq", "cityName:\""+cityName+"\"");
      parameters.set("wt", "json");
      parameters.set("rows", "600");
      parameters.set("indent", true);
```

its querying properly, if I add one more filter query like

```
     parameters.set("fq", "hotels:\""+hotels+"\"");
```

its overwriting city and shows only hotels , need to show hotels from the city
Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue earlier and here is the solution that I applied to resolve this issue:

```
parameters.addFilterQuery("hotels:\""+hotels+"\"","cityName:"+cityName);
```

Example:

```
parameters.addFilterQuery("hotels:\""+Marriot+"\"","cityName:"+Pune);
```

This query will show all the Marriot hotels from Pune City.

I hope this is what you are looking.

Hope this Helps!!!

Jayesh Bhoyar